# How to share structures within several files in my program?

Tags: c

Here's my problem:
I have a big main.c file containing 40 or so "global" structures in my program (they are declared at the begining on the files), I also have several functions in my main.c file that I are able to directly read and write into these structures since they are global.
Now I'm trying to move several function of my original main.c file into another .c file that would contain only the functions related to a specific part of my program. But of course I cannot directly access the main.c global variables from my new .c file.
Is there a way around this?
I'd like to avoid passing every structure by pointer as this would get horrible function prototypes.
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the global structure definitions into a [header (.h) file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file) and just `#include` your header in each c file that needs to access those structures. Any global variables can be declared `extern` and then defined in your main.c.

**Global.h**

```
// WARNING: SHARING DATA GLOBALLY IS BAD PRACTICE

#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

//Any type definitions needed
typedef struct a_struct
{
    int var1;
    long var2;
} a_struct;

//Global data that will be defined in main.c
extern a_struct GlobalStruct;
extern int GlobalCounter;

#endif
```

**main.c**

```
#include "Global.h"
#include "other.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int GlobalCounter;
a_struct GlobalStruct;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GlobalCounter = 5;

    GlobalStruct.var1 = 10;
    GlobalStruct.var2 = 6;

    printf("Counter: %d\nStruct [ var1: %d var2: %ld ]\n", 
           GlobalCounter, GlobalStruct.var1, GlobalStruct.var2);

    do_other_stuff();

    printf("Counter: %d\nStruct [ var1: %d var2: %ld ]\n", 
           GlobalCounter, GlobalStruct.var1, GlobalStruct.var2);

    return 0;   
}
```

**other.h**

```
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H

void do_other_stuff(void);

#endif
```

**other.c**

```
#include "other.h"
#include "Global.h"

void do_other_stuff(void)
{
    GlobalCounter++;
    GlobalStruct.var1 = 100;
    GlobalStruct.var2 = 0xFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Doing this, I get "LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found" linker errors.
Maybe I wasn't clear enough but the structure definition is ok, I just need to be able to share "variables" DECLARATIONS (they could be int) between my .c files. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: Did you use preprocessor checks to make sure the symbols are only defined once? See the File "add.h" section of the wiki article I linked to. `#ifndef _GLOBAL_DATA_H_
#define _GLOBAL_DATA_H_
//Define global structures here
#endif`

Comment: Yeah I did. Does it matter wether I have my #include statements inside or outside the include guards?

Comment: Which include statement are you referring to? All of your variable and type declarations need to be inside of the guards, then include the global header in both files

Comment: ok thanks, this works. But I don't understand why I need to redefine int GlobalCounter;
a_struct GlobalStruct;
in main.c and not in other.c.

Comment: The reason is because of the [extern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable) keyword. This lets the compiler know the variable is allocated else where.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a header file with the declarations for your structs
2. include this header file where needed.

**EDIT**
Sorry for this unfriendly answer.

As you mentioned in your comment, you usually declare your function prototypes in header files. You could use the header files also for declaring:

- variables
- structures

As structures are like classes in C++ in this case, you have to declare the complete body of the struct, to access the struct-members. If you use functions in the struct, you should to implement them in a separate C file.

Comment: "You should learn how to code correctly" I presume that's why he's here asking questions -- to learn.

Comment: @Jay right, but there are basics, you will find on google on every beginner tutorial for C. If you don't known about header files, you will usual miss much more topics, you need to know to write a C program. So, maybe the questioner should start with a simple beginners tutorial first?

Comment: I know how to write header files but it's true I usually just use them to write my function prototypes in them and that's it

Comment: @lezebulon, ok, sry, i will edit my answer and add some more informations

Answer (score 1):

You can access them using `extern`.

In main.c:

```
MY_STRUCT my_global_struct;
```

In otherfile.c:

```
extern MY_STRUCT my_global_struct;
```

Comment: @Downvoter - You took a point or two (oh no) please give some knowledge in return :)

Answer (score 0):

I think global variables should usually be avoided, but to answer your question, you should declare all your structures in a .h file with the `extern` keyword:

```
// my_structs.h
struct A
{
   char c;
};

extern struct A myA; // declare the struct with extern, meaning it will be linked from a different compilation unit

// main.c

#include "my_structs.h"
struct A myA; // actually define struct, all others will be linked to this by the linker
//...

// other.c

#include "my_structs.h"

void accessMyA()
{
    printf ("%c", myA.c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to Joe on the right answer. But I'd add that you should avoid using global data. This makes data flow between functions and modules difficult to track and mysterious. Better to pass the data you need explicitly in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok exposing the structures, then use the header approach from a few other answers.  If not, then pass around void pointers in the global interface and cast to the structure type in the relevant source files.